# ElasticSearch .NET Core TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, .net-core

Running a very simple program (.NET Core 1.0.0-preview2-003121, NEST 2.4.2, Windows 7) that generates documents with random data and pushes them to an ElasticSearch 2.3.4 node running on localhost with `ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g`.

The program batches document inserts and sends them using the BulkPutAsync API. It runs fine for a while, inserting well over 500K documents. Then the program seems to stall, ElasticSearch seems to stop indexing (CPU usage goes down) and finally a `TaskCanceledException` is thrown. ElasticSearch logs are not showing anything suspicious, cluster state is still green.

**Generator.cs:**

```
public static void Generate(params IAdaptor[] adaptors)
{
    ...
    for (int s = 0; s < TotalSemesters; s++)
    {
        ...
        if (responses.Count >= 10000)
        {
            var toInsert = responses.ToArray();
            var insertions = adaptors.Select(a => a.Insert(indexName, toInsert)).ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(insertions);
            responses.Clear();
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**ElasticSearchAdaptor.cs:**

```
public async Task Insert(string indexName, ResponseRootObject[] items)
{
    var objects = new List<object>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        objects.Add(new
        {
            index = new
            {
                _index = indexName,
                _type = "responses"
            }
        });
        objects.Add(item);
    }   

    var r = await _client.BulkPutAsync<ResponseRootObject>(indexName, "responses", new PostData<object>(objects));
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.) ---> Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.<RequestAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.<CallElasticsearchAsync>d__66`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.<RequestAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.<RequestAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Xyz.BusinessIntelligence.DataGenerator.ElasticSearchAdaptor.<Insert>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks)
   at Xyz.BusinessIntelligence.DataGenerator.Generator.Generate(IAdaptor[] adaptors)
   at Xyz.BusinessIntelligence.DataGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could be saturating the threadpool....

Comment: On the generator side? I'm new to .net, how could I address that?

Comment: Make sure that you limit the amount of threads that you create, do 100 at a time. I solved this problem with a Semaphore, but I used the TheadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. You can use `AsParallel` and set the max parallelism

Comment: Thanks. Isn't the async/await API supposed to take care all of that though? Never used it.

Comment: No, it takes care of queuing up the tasks you are giving it. Not you firing millions of tasks at it, and expecting them to execute in a timely manner. Semaphores were created to make sure that you're only executing the right amount of threads at a time.

Comment: You should be careful combining asnyc/await and `Task.WaitAll` you may deadlock yourself if the code gets run inside a synchronization context.

Comment: Yes I removed the Task.WaitAll and the generator doesn't crash anymore. The strange thing is this works fine in a full .NET environment instead of a .NET Core.

Comment: Can you make the `Generator` class async, use `await Task.WhenAll(insertions);` and go async all the way up the call stack?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to go about this. I used `await Task.WhenAll(insertions)` and made `Generator.Generate` async. This last method is called directly in the `Main` method so I couldn't await it and make `Main` async.  End result, the for loop in which this is called exited after one iteration.  I clearly don't understand how this whole async/await thing works, I'll read up more on it.

Comment: @Spiff - in these scenarios, `Main` will be sync, but will call and wait on an async method (I usually call it `MainAsync` for originality), from which everything will be async from this point onwards. Are you checking the response coming back from the bulk calls?

Comment: @Spiff can you wrap `Task.WaitAll(insertions);` in a try/catch then in the catch do `ex.InnerException.ToString()` to get the details of that inner exception and post it here?