# Elasticsearch response is invalid for bots

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I have an ASP .NET Core website that uses Nest to make requests to an elasticsearch server. I am checking if the response IsValid so I can be alerted if there is ever a problem connecting to the elasticsearch server. It works perfectly, except when bots are crawling my website. The only exceptions I get are from bots, like shown below. Any idea what is preventing the bots from crawling my elastic pages properly?

```
var response = client.Get<Category>(cid);
if (!response.IsValid)
{
    throw new Exception("Error connecting to Elastic Server");
}
```

Here is the exception showing the user-agent, with an empty referrer:

> Referrer:  Time: 06/27/2018 11:12 AM Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;
>   Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Path: /Catalog
>   Exception: Error connecting to Elastic Server

Comment: you need to check in your application layer for this issue that you had any sort of condition setup there because at elasticsearch level there is nothing about that request is coming from a bot or real user.

Comment: You also should check the `response.DebugInformation` to understand why the response is determined to not be valid (a non-valid response does not necessarily mean there was an error connecting to Elasticsearch). If there was an exception, `response.OriginalException` will also be set. If Elasticsearch returned an error, `response.ServerError` will be set.

Comment: Thanks. I will add that debug information to the log the next time I deploy the site to production and see what I get.

Comment: From the Nest.IGetResponse   ==>   A task was canceled. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

Comment: I only get these errors with bot user agents. Could it be the way they are sending their requests, so many from a single IP, is there some setting in Elastic that is causing the task to be cancelled?

Comment: Looks like the same problem here. Not sure how to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978101/elasticsearch-net-core-taskcanceledexception